# How can I find a solution to NSolve[]

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following system of 7 equations with 7 unknowns and want to solve it using `NSolve[]`, but cannot do it. MMA gives an empty set, although there is a solution for this.

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
    LL = 134;
    c = {110/493, 150/831, 200/900};
    Y = {262, 168, 164};
    w = {24/493, 49/831, 61/900};
    a = {{0.118, 0.090, 0.109}, {0.249, 0.412, 0.220}, {0.361, 0.259, 
        0.381}};

lag = -Total@Table[c[[j]]*X[j], {j, 3}] + 
   Total@Table[
     P[j]*(X[j] - Total@Table[a[[j, i]]*X[i], {i, 3}] - Y[[j]]), {j, 
      3}] + P[4]*(LL - Total@Table[w[[j]]*X[j], {j, 3}]);


var = Flatten@{Array[X, 3], Array[P, 4]};
system = Thread[D[lag, #] == 0] & /@ var;
NSolve[system, var]
```

Comment: There is even no solution for `NSolve[Thread[D[lag, #] == 0] & /@ Array[X, 3], Array[X, 3]]`  or `NSolve[Thread[D[lag, #] == 0] & /@ Array[PP, 4], Array[PP, 4]]` You should check your `lag` is right.

Comment: There are three equations in `{P[1], P[2], P[3], P[4]}` (underdetermined) and four equations in `{X[1], X[2], X[3]}` (overdetermined).

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci and @Bob Honlon: You are both right. I can get a solution for a given `PP[4]`. But I thought that there is a simultaneously determined solution for `PP[]` and `X[]`. I will update the question with an example of data framework used in the determination of the solution.

Comment: You have to use `PP[1]` form in `NSolve` as a variable

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: Thank you for cleaning and editing the code. When I run `NSolve[Drop[system, -1], Drop[var, -1]]`, which drops the last equation, I find a solution where `P[]` is a function of `P[4]`. At least I get a solution but still my original problem is not solved. I have to reformulate my question. Thank you again.

Comment: In that case P[4] is not a variable but a parameter.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: Yes, I turned it into a parameter, although originally, P[4] is a variable (Lagrange multiplier). As you pointed out, my formulation of `lag` suffers caveats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `P[4]` is a parameter here is a solution.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
LL = 134;
c = {110/493, 150/831, 200/900};
Y = {262, 168, 164};
w = {24/493, 49/831, 61/900};
a = {{0.118, 0.090, 0.109}, {0.249, 0.412, 0.220}, {0.361, 0.259, 
    0.381}};

{varX, varP} = {Array[X, 3], Array[P, 3]};
var = Flatten@{varX, varP};
lag = -c.varX + varP.(varX - a.varX - Y) + P[4] (LL - w.varX);


system = Thread[D[lag, #] == 0] & /@ var;
NSolve[system, var]
```

> {{X[1] -> 493.178, X[2] -> 831.468, X[3] -> 900.464, 
>     P[1] -> 0.784024 + 0.216204 P[4], P[2] -> 0.765818 + 0.235193 P[4], 
>     P[3] -> 0.769242 + 0.231157 P[4]}}

Comment: Yes, I found it as well. I am still trying to reformulate `lag` because I need to find an equilibrium value for `P[4]`, which is an endogenous variable.